# Bash script to replace characters at the end of a string

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script which will take an IP address number in the form `172.19.X.Y` and replace it with `172.19.0.100`.

Unfortunately, I am not that experienced with bash and sed and it is not quite working for me.

So far my closest effort is:

```
PrivateIp=$(sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.\)*$/\10.100/' <<<"$PrivateIp")
```

which produces `172.19.X.Y0.100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\1` is a reference to `\(this\)`, you don't need if you just want to replace.

Just:

```
PrivateIp=$(sed -e 's/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/10.100/' <<<"$PrivateIp")
```

The `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*` will match `<number><dot><number>` The `$` tells it to match from the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, that makes sense to me, and produces the right result (when I removed the 1)

Answer (score 3):

You could use parameter substitution:

```
$ privateip='172.19.X.Y'
$ privateip=${privateip%.*.*}.0.100
$ echo "$privateip"
172.19.0.100
```

`${privateip%.*.*}` removes the shortest match of `.*.*` from the end of `$privateip`, which is `.X.Y` in this case.

Comment: Yes, you are right that one works too (and is perhaps simpler to read)